# Why my machine isn't using equaly the all vCPUs?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sentry

I am working with Sentry on-premise in one AWS EC2 m5.large instance in Docker but I am in front of a problem: My 2vCPUs aren't using equaly. One of them was with 100% and the other with less than 5%. Why this happen?

[Print of the htop command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv670.png)

Comment: Questions about general computing, as opposed to the practice of writing software, should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), not here.

Comment: ...bottom line is that writing software to parallelize well requires deliberate effort, and apparently the Sentry folks didn't put that in (or it just wasn't feasible) for the kind of workload you have at hand.

Comment: (last time I was part of a project specifically aimed at rewriting software -- indeed, an event-streaming analytics engine -- to parallelize well, the approach we took was a rewrite in Clojure to use its STM primitives for lock-free concurrency; that was not *at all* a small engineering effort, and I won't blame anyone for not making it until/unless they have a real and compelling need to; moreover, at only two cores, the overhead required probably would have eaten up the benefits -- it was a net throughput increase for us, but we were running on hardware with upwards of 40 cores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with running Apache Flink in docker,
when we removed the port mapping (8081) it was solved, looks like this malware exploits known ports (e.g redis,flink and others) for remote code execution.
check your port mapping and firewall.
maybe try to map to a not so popular port number of put your docker instance behind an nginx instance and do prefix routing.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, this was caused by a malware called kdevtmpfsi, a miner.
I am trying to remove this cleaning the machine and creating a VPN

Comment: Note that this is an answer focused system administration practices. SO is only for questions about software development, not system administration.